# Python, adding comma in smtplib argument causes error

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtplib

While sending an email with smtplib and trying to insert a variable into the message with this code:

```
smtpObj.sendmail('my email', 'my email', "Subject: Info for today.  \nToday's weather is:",con)
```

(where con is weather scraped from the internet)

throws the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 731, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (501, '5.5.4 Invalid arguments', 'my email here')
```

However, when I simply use "+" to concatenate the two strings, rather than a comma, it works, but does not format properly, displaying as "..weather is:rain" rather than "..weather is: rain"

am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I simply use "+" to concatenate the two strings, rather than a comma, it works, but does not format properly, displaying as "..weather is:rain" rather than "..weather is: rain"

You are simply mis-constructing the string that begins with "Subject" here:

```
smtpObj.sendmail('my email', 'my email', "Subject: Info for today.  \nToday's weather is:",con)
```

When you tack on `con` with a comma like you are doing here, Python thinks that you are passing `conn` as the `mail_options` argument of the [`sendmail()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) call, the same as your other arguments to that function. It does not understand that you are trying to cram `con` into that "Subject: ..." string.

> However, when I simply use "+" to concatenate the two strings, rather than a comma, it works, but does not format properly, displaying as "..weather is:rain" rather than "..weather is: rain"

So you just need an extra space after the "..weather is:" bit? Just add the extra space in the string. I suggest you write your message with the `con` argument in one of these ways:

```
msg = "Subject: Info for today.  \nToday's weather is: " + con
# or like this:
msg = "Subject: Info for today.  \nToday's weather is: %s" % (con,)
```

And then send your email:

```
smtpObj.sendmail('my email', 'my email', msg)
```